# Lightning component for email template - error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, email-template, aura

I'm redirecting the user from my lightning component to Lightning Email template creation popup.
Currently, the user has access to create there own from setup but to eliminate going to setup, I've set a redirect to the lightning email template creation page using `$A.get("e.force:navigateToURL")`

Following is the code,

```
onNewEmailTempCreate : function(component, event, helper) {
        var sel = component.find("Template").get("v.value");
        if(sel === 'New Email Template'){
            var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
            urlEvent.setParams({
                "url": "/lightning/o/EmailTemplate/new?count=1&nooverride=1&useRecordTypeCheck=1&navigationLocation=LIST_VIEW&backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fo%2FEmailTemplate%2Fhome"
            });
            urlEvent.fire();
        }

    },
```

This code is working fine in redirecting and showing the creation page but I see following error  when saving, "Template Unique Name must be provided.: Template Unique Name
RelatedEntityType can only be specified for SFX Custom Templates.: Custom Object Definition ID"

[image]

The name i'm using is unique and doesn't already exist.

Please let me know if i'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as said in the error you need to set the 'UiType'(Indicates the user interface where this template is usable) to 'SFX' and 'TemplateType' to custom you can do this

```
onNewEmailTempCreate : function(component, event, helper) {

        var createAcountContactEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createAcountContactEvent.setParams({
            "entityApiName": "EmailTemplate",
            "defaultFieldValues": {
                'UiType' :'SFX',
                'TemplateType':'custom'



            }
        });
        createAcountContactEvent.fire();

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, do you if this can be opened in a new tab instead of current page?

Comment: @Anurag if you will launch above event in console app it will automatically take you to different tab,in nomal app the best i can think of is you can launch another component on button click and in init of other component fire this event which will open it in another tab but still in popup